How to streamline the colour style of differently coloured applications in one ecosystem
I am stuck, and I really need advice or just an external opinion.
I am designing 3 different applications for a HR tech startup. One is to match candidates to a job, one is to schedule them in a job and one is to pay and contract them. These 3 applications all fall under one provider, but they can be bought and used separately and each have their own distinct colour. Other than the colour they all belong visually to the same family. So far so good, but from within these applications a user can access the candidate's details, which are centralized and need to be accessed the exact same way from each application. This opens up a modal in that application rather than go to another application. Since it's centralized it should have a neutral colour.
But it clashes with the other color schemes if used within. A button link in the main app would be, say, orange, while in the neutral modal it would be dark blue. It doesn't make sense to me, and it also doesn't make sense that the neutral modal would be differently coloured in each application. I don't know what to do here. My thought was to just keep the different colour mainly for the logo and some other non-functional elements you can't click one, and keep all other buttons or interactive elements in the neutral colour.
I don't even know if there are similar cases out there that do the same, so I could use some advice here. Thx


could you please clarify why exactly modal can't open with color scheme of calling product? Are there other popups or this is the only one? I guess at some point it closes and user goes back to calling app, right? So popup already knows who called it and can adapt colors

The question is about a possible adaptation of the colour between the buttons of each application+modal, but there is a condition that contradicts it:

it doesn't make sense that the neutral modal button would be differently coloured in each application

From which it follows that it is not about looking for a colour change at all. Therefore the title is meaningless:

How to streamline the colour style of differently coloured
applications in one ecosystem

Based on what is seen in the screenshot, and knowing that the colour is not modifiable, I would look for another type of alternative solution.
The problem is the pairing by visual association between the applications, whose buttons have:

Same shape
Same style
Same layout (aligned to the right)

If the dissociation by colour is the problem, I would look to differentiate the interactive elements by exaggerating the contrast with a marked visual typology for each element (apps/modal): one design for the applications and another for the modal windows, without losing the graphic systematization. You should find the one that best fits the overall design of the application.
For example:


Thanks for the feedback. Not sure if I fully understand, but I find your answer odd though, that a user encounters two different buttons within the same application, in colour and style. To me, a UI should stay consistent, either in modal and non-modal. Otherwise, the user feels even more dissociated. The colour per application might be fixed now, but given enough substantiated feedback, we might be able to change it, and only leave non-interactive UI elements in that colour, like I said. So I'm looking for a solution whereby it feels coherent.

My answer is not a solution, it is just a starting point to try to find a solution. The example images are not final proposals, the one who designs the application is you, so it is your responsibility to find the most feasible option. What is obvious is that at some point you will have to make a decision, simple or odd.
